# button image issue (css)

Tags: css

This is my css for a paypal sprite I have made..

Image below shows what we get in Internet Explorer and what we get in Firefox ..

The code to display the sprite is:

```
.ppsprite {
background: url('/images/paypal_sprite.png')no-repeat scroll 0px 0px transparent;
width:200px;
height:100px;
position:absolute;
left:54px;
}
 .ppsprite:hover {
background: url('/images/paypal_sprite.png')no-repeat scroll 0px -100px transparent;
}
```

The code to display the sprite ( html )

```
<input class="ppsprite" type="image" name="submit" alt="">
```

The screenpic ( internet explorer and firefox )

[image]

The sprite works perfectly in all browsers, but you can see a shitty border in IE and a kind of missing image icon top left.
In chrome and safari, pretty much same ( but shows alt text on top of sprite )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a src attribute to your input tag:

```
<input class="ppsprite" type="image" name="submit" alt="" src="images/blank.gif">
```

Just create a file called blank.gif
You don't need to do anything with it, just make sure it's in the right directory.

Comment: perfect I had forgotten this: added 1px gif

Comment: Now you've added an image (1 more hit on the server) while still using a CSS sprite that won't always display (in **[High Contrast mode](http://yaccessibilityblog.com/library/high-contrast-friendly-icons.html) on Windows and many more situations)** and there's still no `@alt` for these cases (or maybe you removed it in this example?). Why not use an HTML image that won't cost you any performance hit (it trades your `blank.gif` from 1999 for a `paypal_buynow.png`)?

Answer (score 1):

don't use an image-input for your sprite - obviously this *should* show a broken-link-icon as it must contain an image (set via the `src`-attrtibute) but you dont set one. maybe you can replace the `input` with an `a` (a link) or a button (`type="button"` or `type="submit"`). the later should work without changing anything else as a `type="submit"` would still submit the form, just like `type="image"` does (and i don't think you'll need to know the klicked x/y-coordinates in this case).

the border simply appears because an input-image has a border by default in some browsers - simply set `border:0;` for `.ppsprite` (but, as said, you shouldn't use an input-image at all in this case).